# Можно ли сделать прозрачный для нажатий фон?

Tags: html, css

Пытаюсь сделать игру, когда надо находить блоки, а поверх фон потихоньку все темнел и темнел. Следовательно нужно, чтобы верхний слой был прозрачным для нажатий, но его вид можно было бы менять. А нижний слой работал бы как обычная `html` страница.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать `pointer-events: none;` для фона:

```css
.background {
  background-color: #f80;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: .5;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="background"></div>
<a href="#" onclick="alert('Click')">Click</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно, для этого задайте [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events): none;

Данное значение "скроет" элемент от событий мыши, хотя его потомки могут быть видны для них.

> The element is never the target of mouse events; however, mouse events
>   may target its descendant elements if those descendants have
>   pointer-events set to some other value